# Is string spliting formally defined when the string delimiter is an empty string?

Tags: strings, substrings, string-matching

Depending on the API/language you use, splitting the string `"ABCD"` using `""` as a delimiter gets you:

- `["A", "B", "C", "D"]` in [Java](https://onlinegdb.com/r18ymdtRD), Javascript, and [Go](https://play.golang.org/p/ylUTXYp9TCT)
- `["", "A", "B", "C", "D", ""]` in [Rust](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8347309133d2bd12bf1b0ed51c49fb1a)
- `["ABCD"]` in [C#](https://dotnetfiddle.net/03Iq9f)
- Fails with an Exception in [Python3](https://onlinegdb.com/2_kl24xp6)

From the perspective of formal language design, what is *the* correct result of such an operation? Is it defined?

Disclosure: This question was [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65662522/10126273) at stack overflow but was closed as opinion-based. I was directed to post my question here instead.

Comment: Formal language design? Do you mean "design of programming lanaguges" or "theory of formal languages"?

Comment: I am not familiar with formal languages theory at all so I would go with the former. I used the word Formal here in an attempt to convey "Well-definedness"  and coherency with other string functions. In hindsight, my adding the `formal-languages` tag was probably a mistake.

Comment: It seems opinion-based to me too.  I'm not sure why moving it to a different site would change that conclusion.  The question contains a premise that there is a single correct result but I don't think that premise is accurate.  You can define it any way you want.

Comment: @D.W. I'm very lousy at presenting questions: What I was asking for is 1) whether a *single* canonical result for splitting strings by an empty string *has been formally defined*, and 2) what is it if has been. I'm *not* asking people to give me their opinion on how a canonical result should look like. Your (and @Andrej's) answer that *no such canonical result has been defined* is a completely valid and (imho) objective answer. That said, all this confusion is entirely my fault. I apologize for my poorly wording my questions.

Comment: That's the great thing about definitions: you can define anything you want.  In this case I expect which is the best or "canonical" of these definitions is likely to be a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given sequences $A = [a_1, \ldots, a_n]$ and $B = [b_1, \ldots, b_m]$, write $A + B = [a_1, \ldots, a_n, b_1, \ldots, b_m]$ for their concatenation. Given a sequence of sequences $C = [C_1, \ldots, C_n]$, write $\Sigma(C) = C_1 + \cdots + C_n$ for their concatenation.

Define a **splitting of a sequence $X$ by a sequence $Y$** to be a sequence of sequences $Z = [Z_1, \ldots, Z_k]$ such that $Z_i \neq Y$ and $Z_i \neq []$ for all $i = 1, \ldots, k$, and
$$X = \Sigma [Z_1, Y, Z_2, Y, z_3, \ldots, Y, Z_k].$$

For example, $[[a], [], [b, c]]$ is a splitting of $[a, u, v, u, v, b, c]$ by $[u, v]$.

Splitting by the empty sequence is not unique: $[a, b, c]$ may be split by $[]$ in several ways, among others $[[a],[b],[c]]$, $[[a,b], [c]]$ and $[[a,b,c]]$. From a theoretical point this is a rather trivial and non-interesting observation. The implementors of various string libraries need to deal with splitting by the empty sequence somehow, and as you show, they do.

Comment: So having a single canoncial result for this operation doesn't make sense. All results are equally correct as long as joining the segments together yields the original string. Got it.

Comment: I do have two small questions about your answer: According to your definition of the split operation, wouldn't Rust's implementation be incorrect since it yields Z[i] = Y? Also, in your example bellow the definition, did you mean to express the Y as `[u,b]` or `[u,v]`? Apologies if these questions are nonsensical. I don't have much experience in the field of Computer Science.

Comment: @TendersMcChiken: `[u,b]` was a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: @TendersMcChiken: I included the conditions $Z_i \neq Y$ and $Z_i \neq []$ so that the splitting is unique in case $Y \neq []$. If you drop those conditions, then you get many more splittings. For example $[[a, u, v], [b, c]]$ and $[[], [], [], [a], [], [b, c]]$ would both be splittings of $[a, u, v, u, v, b, c]$ by $[u,  v]$. I don't know what the Rust designeres where thinking. I would guess they were not thinking about the border-line cases, unless there is something in the documentation indicating otherwise.